# Sachverhalt vs Sachlage

Tags: meaning, difference

Was bedeuten Sachverhalt und Sachlage (nicht im philosophischen Kontext)?

Sind sie austauschbar oder nicht?

> Der Abgeordnete hielt eine Rede zur aktuellen **Sachlage**.
>
> **Die Sachlage** wird in Deutschland falsch dargestellt.
>
> **Die Sachlage** ist, dass er ein schwer verlaufender Form von Muskelschwund hat.
>
> Heute ist **die Sachlage** leider unverändert und er läuft weiterhin schlecht.

---

> **Der Sachverhalt** wurde erst jetzt bei der Polizei bekannt.
>
> Man kann sich eben doch auf dich verlassen. (DOCH bestätigt **einen Sachverhalt**, den man für unwahrscheinlich hielt)
>
> Wir werden **den Sachverhalt** vor Ort überprüfen.
>
> Er schickte uns dieses Bild einer Tierrettung und möchte damit auf **einen Sachverhalt** hinweisen.

Comment: Bitte seht davon ab, Antworten in Kommentaren zu schreiben.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Hast du Kommentare gelöscht? Meinen zum Beispiel?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ja. Andere wurden von ihren Autoren gelöscht. (Falls Du dies weiter diskutieren möchtest, vermutlich am besten auf Meta oder im Chat.)

Answer (score 8):

Der **Sachverhalt** gibt eine Beschreibung des Ist-Zustands und hat den Anspruch komplett zu sein. Der Sachverhalt hat den Anspruch eine korrekte Wiedergabe des Ist-Zustands zu sein.

Die **Sachlage** ist eine Sammlung von Beschreibungen des Ist-Zustands ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit, beziehungsweise erklärt unvollständig. Die Sachlage macht stärker auf die subjektive Natur der Beobachtungen die ihr zugrunde liegen aufmerksam, und hat damit lediglich den Anspruch eine korrekte Wiedergabe der (möglicherweise falschen) Beschreibungen des Ist-Zustands zu sein.

Gerne wird der Sachverhalt aber durch den Sprachgebrauch abgemildert: "Der Sachverhalt stellt sich bislang so dar: [...]" - Hier könnte auch "Die Sachlage ist: [...]" stehen.

Comment: Zumindest in der Wissenschaftstheorie muss ein [Sachverhalt keine korrekte Aussage sein](https://books.google.de/books?id=HobWMckqtNMC&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

In Ergänzung zu den anderen Antworten (Vollständigkeit, Komplexität) gibt es noch einen zeitlichen Aspekt. Ohne weitere Attribuierung bezieht sich die **Sachlage** auf einen gegenwärtigen Informationsstand. Daran ändert sich im Prinzip nichts, wenn der Zeitpunkt ausdrücklich bestimmt wird – es gilt/galt dann der zum spezifizierten Zeitpunkt verfügbare Informationsstand.

Insbesondere kann sich die Sachlage in Abhängigkeit von weiterer eintreffender Information ändern.

> Die Sachlage gestern war die Unkenntnis über den Verbleib der Einnahmen des Festes und die Vermutung, Vereinsmitglied X habe diese Gelder veruntreut.
>
> Die Sachlage heute ist, daß die Gelder bei X aufgetaucht sind, der Verdacht weiterhin besteht.
>
> Die Sachlage morgen könnte sein, daß X den Verdacht gegen ihn zerstreuen konnte (etwa durch Nachweis, daß er im Auftrag des Vorstands handelte)

Im Gegensatz hierzu behält ein einmal festgestellter **Sachverhalt** seine Gültigkeit.

Comment: guter Punkt! +1

Comment: Kannst Du das irgendwie belegen? Kommt mir sehr willkürlich vor. Die Zeit, auf die sich etwas bezieht, wird ja immer durch die Zeitform des Verbs bestimmt - das gilt freilich für alle Wörter.

Answer (score -1):

Den Unterschied sehe ich in erster Linie in der Komplexität. »Sachverhalt« verwendet man eher bei einzelnen Fakten, »Sachlage« eher bei einem Faktenbündel.

*Beispiele für Sachverhalt*

> - Der Händler hat gelogen
> - Mein Auto wurde geklaut
> - Orloff hat keinen Fernseher

*Beispiel für Sachlage*

> »Wie ist die Sachlage?«
>   »Wir haben eine Leiche, eine aufgebrochene Terrassentür, Blut- und Fußspuren, Fingerabdrücke und eine Katze, die den Leichnam angeknabbert hat.«

Comment: Das stimmt so nicht. Ein Sachverhalt ist die Menge aller Tatsachen. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachverhalt Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Nicht unbedingt. Wie Wiki es schreibt kommt es auf den Bereich an in dem man sich bewegt. Sachverhalte sind bei WIki zunächst einmal die "inhaltliche Gesamtheit aller Aussagen zu einem abgegrenzten Themenbereich". Diese Aussagen können auch unwahr sein und sind dann keine Tatsachen. Ein Sachverhalt kann auch einer einzelnen Aussage entsprechen. Die Duden-Definition, die deiner entspricht, wird dort anderen unter [Allgemeines](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachverhalt#Allgemeines) gegenüber gestellt.

Comment: @Ja, OK, es die Aussagen müssen nicht wahr sein. In jedem Fall ist aber nicht die Komplexität das Unterscheidungskriterium.